# Trying to build Unity project for HoloLens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I try to build a Unity Project for the HoloLens and get the following error:

Operation UnityEditor.PackageManager.Requests.SearchRequest failed with Error: UnityEditor.PackageManager.Error
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Can you give us a piece of code? A complete, minimal and verifiable example?

Comment: I started a new project and wanted to test if I can build in generally, so there is actually no code...

Comment: How exactly do you try to build? Could you show your build settings etc?

Comment: I don't believe that is a build error. I think that error occurs in the unity editor.  Try clearing the console before running/building and seeing if you still have errors.

Answer (score 0):

Anything using the `UnityEditor` namespace will **only** be available inside of Unity. The `UnityEditor` namespace is completely stripped off in a build.

Make sure you don't rely on any `UnityEditor` classes in your runtime scripts.

To avoid build errors from files using that namespace there are two options:

1. If they appear in custom editor scripts move those scripts into folders called `Editor`. Anything placed on such a folder will also not be compiled into the final build but only available inside of Unity.
2. Use the pre-processors

   ```
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
   using UnityEditor;
   using UnityEditor.Internal;
   // Etc
   #endif
   ```

   and than also

   ```
   #if UNITY_EDITOR  
   // Some code using UnityEditor stuff here
   #endif
   ```

   everywhere in your scripts around stuff that shall use the `UnityEditor` namespace and only available inside of Unity but stripped off in the build.